# What is $5$ taken to the power iota?

Tags: complex-numbers

Could someone please solve this. I tried to put it in Euler's form but that wasn't any use because

$$5 = 5e^{i\cdot0}=5.$$

Comment: With "iota" do you mean the [Imaginary unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_unit) $i$ ?

Comment: Maybe $e^{0i}$ ?

Comment: To the upvoter : How is this question clear ? "iota" is not a common terminology, I think. And the guess "i" does not fit to what we have in the body.

Comment: @Peter As I recall, the imaginary constant $i$ is technically not the Latin letter 'i' but the Greek iota. I think this is more common in some countries than others.

Comment: @Graviton Do you have a citation for that claim?  In every text I have ever read, the imaginary unit is either an $i$ or (to some engineers) a $j$.  I've even seen a blackboard bold $\mathbb{i}$ used for the imaginary unit.  I have never seen $\iota$ used for the imaginary unit.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I believe it's more common in India. I remember watching videos such as [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eh0Lm6foIkU&ab_channel=CBSEPLUS)  that use iota when I was first learning about complex numbers online. As a Canadian I cannot confirm this.

Comment: @XanderHenderson  Also, on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_unit) it notes "Some texts use the Greek letter iota (ι) for the imaginary unit to avoid confusion, especially with indices and subscripts."

Comment: @Graviton With respect to the Wikipedia citation, it is worth noting that the assertion is disputed, and that there is a tag there asking for citations.  That being said, I can certainly believe that this may be a regional thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to calculate $5^i$. In which case you'd convert it into polar form by

$$5^i=(e^{\ln5})^i=e^{i\ln5}$$

Note that for any positive real number $a$, by definition of the natural logarithm, $a=e^{\ln a}$.
Also, remember the power rule $(a^{b})^c=a^{bc}$.

Now that we have $5^i$ in the form $e^{i\theta}$, we can use Euler's formula

$$e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$$
$$\implies5^i=e^{i\ln5}=\cos(\ln5)+i\sin(\ln5)$$

This number is really close to $i$, in fact,

$$5^i\approx-0.039+0.999i$$

This is due to $\ln5\approx\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: First , it should be clarified what the author means.

Comment: @Peter Though I agree that OP's question is confounding, it's my personal opinion that you're over-moderating. OP's question is "What is 5 taken to the power iota?", and in the question-body OP seems to be attempting to convert $5$ into a something workable through Euler's polar formula. I think my assumption covers a basis that would (at the very least) provide valuable insight for OP.

Comment: @Graviton The fact that a question can be parsed and interpreted does not mean that the question is clear or appropriate for this site.  This particular question is of poor quality for a number of reasons, including lack of clarity.  Please try not to answer low-quality questions.  Instead, it might be more helpful to help the asker to improve the quality of their question.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Alright, thank you for the explanation. You're right, this does reinforce questions of unclear nature.